# Model comparison: with raw or normalized data?

Tags: logistic, normalization, model-comparison

I have developed a index of drug addiction risk whose formula is  `Index` = 1/log10(a_given_variable). The raw values of the calculated `Index` range from -4 to 0. Since I wanted the Index to be expressed on a scale of 1 (lowest risk) to 10 (highest risk), I normalized the `Index` with the following min-max formula:

`Index_normalized` = (xi - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x))

Now I want to know if my index is a good predictor of drug addiction risk compared to log10(`Literature_var`), which is a good predictor know from literature. To this end, I want to use logistic regression models, using a dataset where `Addicted` was the dependent variable (0 = non-addicted and 1 = addicted) and log10(`Literature_var`) and my index are the independent continuous variables in distinct single-term models. In particular, I compared log10(`Literature_var`) with both the raw and normalized version of my index, i.e. with both `Index` and `Index_normalized`, using the AIC to identify the most parsimonious model. In R:

**Model 1a:** glm(Addicted ~ Index_normalized, data = df, family = "binomial")

**Model 1b:** glm(Addicted ~ Index, data = df, family = "binomial")

versus

**Model 2:** glm(Addicted ~ log10(Literature_var), data = df, family = "binomial")

I expected the same performance but obtained opposite results, with `Index_normalized` being better than log10(`Literature_var`) (much lower AIC), and `Index` being worse (much higher AIC).

My doubt is about which of the two proposed models (Model 1a or Model 1b) is the correct one. That is, should I compare Literature_var with the raw values of `Index`, or with the normalized values of the desired 1-to-10 `Index_normalized`?

Or maybe should I apply the same normalization formula to the other variable log10(`Literature_var`)?

Thank you

Comment: I assume you mean (xi - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)) ? And what is your model exactly? By "Addicted ~ Index" do you mean "logit-probability for addicted = intercept + regression coefficient * index" or do you mean "logit-probability for addicted = regression coefficient * index"? If it's the latter, then that would explain it.

Comment: I corrected the normalization formula, thank  you. Regarding the model, I added the R code, I am using a binomial GLM whose output for each model is the intercept + regression coefficient. So, for prediction of addiction risk, for example, I would calculate log-odds with the formula intercept + regression coefficient * Index  or Index_normalized or log10(Literature_var), respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You say you know for sure that log10(Literature_var) is a good index.
Therefore I think I would start with checking whether you the two forms of the index you calculated are correlated with it.

Then, in order to compare the performance of the 3 potential indexes (literature, index & normalized index) I believe what you want is the amount of variance in "Addicted" that is explained by each of the 3 models you have built. This can be done by comparing the likelihood ratio between each of the 3 models to the null model `Model 0: glm(Addicted ~ 1, data = df, family = "binomial")`
Then you could use `lrtest`
with an R command which would look a bit like :
`lrtest(Model 0,Model 1a)`  then `lrtest(Model 0,Model 1b)` and finally `lrtest(Model 0,Model 2)`

Comment: Actually, I am not interested in exploring the correlation with Log10(Literature_var), I am interested in finding statistical evidence for my Index_normalized, where for evidence I mean the AIC of the corresponding model is lower than that of the model with Log10(Literature_var). I obtained this but the problem is that if I compare Log10(Literature_var) with the raw values of the index I get the opposite (independently from the correlation). So I am not sure if when I am affirming that my Index_normalized is a good predictor I am mistaken because I should compare the raw values instead.

Comment: Still, you should know whether they are at least correlated.

Comment: Do you mean that I could use the strength of the correlation between Log10(Literature_var) and Index_normalized as a point to statistically validate my Index_normalized? Thank you for your input